# Network drive sharing when RPi is file server

Tags: mount, samba, permissions

I'm using a Pi4 as a file server. Everything was fine - USB drives are mounted, Samba shares makes them available to the network. No issues until I reformatted the drives as ext4. I moved the data, mounted the drives and set up samba again. The drives show up, but they are read only.  My Linux Mint machine tells me that root is the owner. Windows gives an error message. I suspect I'm missing something obvious. I have tried setting the owner and the permissions on the drives.  They all look good on the Pi, but they don't carry over to the Samba share.

More specifics: On the Pi, the drives are mounted in fstab as follows:

```
#Local Disks  
UUID=27705094-8dd5-4f2f-a854-576cfb011f76 /mnt/5tb3 ext4 defaults 0 0  
UUID=f1029e86-3e6c-497e-bdeb-3672941db372 /mnt/5tb2 ext4 defaults 0 0  
UUID=44ba2a5d-e984-4716-b8dd-0d99e6c92489 /mnt/5tb1 ext4 defaults 0 0  
UUID=e2550d94-ec3b-46ab-8b78-e9ef30a81c07 /mnt/2tb ext4 defaults
```

The samba shares are all set up the same

```
[5tb1]  
    comment = 5tb1  
    path = /mnt/5tb1  
    browseable = yes  
    writeable = yes  
    only guest = no  
    create mask = 0777  
    directory mask = 0777  
    public = yes  
    guest ok = yes
```

Then they are mounted on my dual boot Windows/Mint laptop in fstab

```
#Network Drives  
//raspberrypi/5tb1  /mnt/5tb1  cifs  x-systemd.automount,username=user,password=pass 0 0  
//raspberrypi/5tb2  /mnt/5tb2  cifs  x-systemd.automount,username=user,password=pass 0 0
```

I think the permissions on the drives look good from the Pi:

```
mot@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -al /mnt  
total 32  
drwxr-xr-x  8 root    root  4096 Oct  2 11:08 .  
drwxr-xr-x 18 root    root  4096 May  2 20:36 ..  
drwxrwxrwx  7 mycroft users 4096 Oct 12 20:08 2tb  
drwxrwxrwx  5 mycroft users 4096 Oct 10 19:20 5tb1  
drwxrwxrwx  6 mycroft users 4096 Oct  5 12:05 5tb2  
drwxrwxrwx  7 mycroft users 4096 Oct 10 19:40 5tb3  
drwxrwxrwx  3 mycroft users 4096 Oct  2 11:08 Laurie  
drwxrwxrwx  3 mycroft users 4096 Oct  2 11:08 yogalaptop  
mot@raspberrypi:~ $
```

But from my Mint machine, root is the owner, and I can't change the permissions.
[image]

In Windows, I can map the drive, but it comes up as read only.

Thanks for looking at all this.  If you have any ideas, let me know. I'm sure it's soemthing simple.  This can't be as hard as it seems right now!

#### EDIT:

The old `fstab` entry was:

```
UUID=1062310A6230F5D6 /mnt/5tb1 ntfs uid=user,gid=group 0 0
```

and the new one is:

```
UUID=44ba2a5d-e984-4716-b8dd-0d99e6c92489 /mnt/5tb1 ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Comment: This *appears* to be a problem with Linux Mint... why are you asking about Linux Mint here in RPi SE?

Comment: Actually, I don't think it's a Mint issue because I have the same problem in both Mint and Windows. Thanks for the thought!

Comment: Well, *actually*...     being common to Mint and Windows does not change the *appearance*.  I understand that RPi is the file server, but simply re-formatting to `ext4` would not cause the problem you describe.

Comment: Good point, Seamus - I didn't think re-formatting to ext4 would cause problems either, but the problem is there. Re-mounting the drives *did* require mounting it with different parameters. The old fstab entry was
UUID=1062310A6230F5D6 /mnt/5tb1 ntfs uid=user,gid=group 0 0  
and the new one is
UUID=44ba2a5d-e984-4716-b8dd-0d99e6c92489 /mnt/5tb1 ext4 defaults 0 0.  
I tried force user = user and force group = group, with no luck.  
Is there some other parameter I am missing?

Comment: Coupla' things: First on the *format* for *Comments*: When you're addressing a comment to a specific user - one who **is not** the author of the Q or A under which the comment appears - you should preface that comment with that specific user's **handle**; *e.g.* `@seamus`.

Comment: Second, I *now feel* that your issue is due (or related) to your `/etc/fstab` entries & possibly your Samba config. You may find *some benefit* to reading these two recipes on my GitHub site: [1](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/ExternalDrives.md), [2](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/CreatingRationalMusicLibrary.md). Take a look at them. In the meantime, I'll ***start*** an answer below.

Comment: @Seamus - Thanks for your help! I went through your two recipes, and they were very helpful. The first recipe, on mounting drives, was relevant to my drive mounting process. The example does not use an ext4 formatted drive however, so some of those mounting details will be different. The other recipe, on building a music server, was very relevant to the Samba connections in my issue. Unfortunately, you seem to use the same samba configuration that I have, but with no connectivity issues. I'm stuck.

Comment: OK - we'll try brute force :)  I should have an answer to post shortly. One question: Are you set on `samba`/CIFS - or would you consider another file-sharing protocol... e.g. `sshfs`??

Comment: @Seamus - I'm not wedded to Samba, but I need the Pi to serve files for Windows and Unix machines. I honestly haven't looked at other options.

Comment: Right... I've no way to test it, but I [did read in at least one source](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/sshfs) that `sshfs` worked on Windows. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Q omits some details, but I feel that *part* of the problem is in the `/etc/fstab` entries - the ones in your RPi, and/or the ones in your Linux Mint machine. Let's approach the issues raised in your question in this order:

- the `fstab` in your RPi server
- the `fstab` in your Linux Mint client (if necessary)
- the `samba` config (if necessary)

#### Part I: The `fstab` on your RPi server

Using the ***terminal on your RPi***, do this:

```bash
$ lsblk --fs
```

Following is the output on **my system**:

```
NAME        FSTYPE FSVER LABEL       UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sda
└─sda1      ext4   1.0   PASSPORT2TB 86645948-d127-4991-888c-a466b7722f05    1.5T    10% /mnt/Passport2TB
sdb
├─sdb1      vfat   FAT16             6969-16D1                             205.9M    19% /mnt/sdpi/boot
└─sdb2      ext4   1.0               f6ea6ef9-68be-479d-b447-5f76391cc02f   22.9G    17% /mnt/sdpi/root
mmcblk0
├─mmcblk0p1 vfat   FAT32 bootfs      CEE7-0DF0                             203.6M    20% /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 ext4   1.0   rootfs      ebadab55-bd70-46a9-8f18-995c136fb5b2   54.1G     3% /
```

- See the notes below on the `lsblk --fs` command<sup>Note 1</sup>.

Let's take a look at the entry in the RPi's `/etc/fstab` that produced the output from `lsblk --fs` above:

```
# Add the PASSPORT2TB mount
LABEL=PASSPORT2TB /mnt/Passport2TB ext4 rw,user,nofail 0 0
```

- Note that in this entry, the `LABEL` is used as identification *instead of* the `UUID`. Use of `LABEL` instead of `UUID` is criticized by some because it's not *Unique*, but for small-ish personal networks without hundreds of devices, using a unique `LABEL` is [*common sense*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/common-sense).

As with most things, it's always good practice to consult the system manuals before going off half-cocked, or on the basis of some *blog* that may have been posted by a [half-wit](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/half-wit). In this case, on RPi, from the terminal, do this to see the ***local*** manual for `fstab`:

```bash
$ man fstab
```

The `manual` identifies each of the six (6) *fields* used in an `fstab` entry, and tells us that their *order is important*. *If the RPi is the server of this partition for other systems on your network, this is all you need.<sup>Note 2</sup>* `fstab` entries for other systems (client systems) can be more complex...

##### *However*...

- I'm a bit suspicious of the use of the `defaults` option in your `fstab` entry. Why? Partly because all default values are not explained fully in `man fstab`, and partly because of the *Debian factor* (Debian has been known to *change things* in their distro - and therefore the RPi OS distro). To keep things straight, suggest you use `rw,user,nofail` in the *fourth field* just for now - instead of `defaults`.

#### Part II: the `fstab` in your Linux Mint/Windows client (if necessary)

##### Part II-A: Samba

Your Mint client `fstab` entries to the RPi server's Samba shares appear to be reasonable (although the `noauto` option is typically used). However, Mint configuration is a wee bit *off-topic* here, and since you're reporting issues, it seems a good idea to limit the variables. Consequently, I'll suggest the following changes to your Mint client `fstab` entries which try to avoid  potential complications brought in by the use of `systemd` (`systemd.mount`). Since you are mounting a Samba share (`cifs`), you should refer to `man mount.cifs` as the source for options used in `/etc/fstab`.

```
//raspberrypi/5tb1  /mnt/5tb1  cifs rw,nofail,username=user,password=pass,vers=3,uid=pi,gid=pi,file_mode=0644 0 0
```

You should also verify that `cifs-utils` is installed on the Mint client.

##### Part II-B: sshfs - a recommended alternative to Samba:

For Linux-to-Linux filesharing (and even on Windows, according to [this source](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/sshfs)), I'll suggest you take a look at `sshfs` as an alternative to Samba. It's simpler, more consistent and more secure. Here's how:

1. on your *client* (Mint), install `sshfs`

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install sshfs
```

2. set up a mountpoint on Mint:

```bash
sudo mkdir /mnt/rpi-sshfs
```

3. connect to your RPi server from Mint:

```bash
$ sudo sshfs -o allow_other,default_permissions pi@raspberrypi:/mnt/Passport2TB /mnt/rpi-sshfs  

The authenticity of host 'raspberrypi (192.168.1.144)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:hrj8Y9wQ4IUjAINAY9uwicdqQJwhRAHg4TwDBZhKw6g.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
pi@raspberrypi4b's password:
```

This example (above) shows a *manual* `sshfs` mount using passwords. The same mount can be made at startup using the `/etc/fstab` file if you have generated a *public-private key pair* using `ssh-keygen` (see the tutorials listed below for details).

There are several tutorials and *how-tos* available on `sshfs` for the cost of an Internet search. Here's one from [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/understanding-sshfs), [another one](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/sshfs) and [this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh).

For the Mint client, once you've read the tutorial(s), the following `/etc/fstab` entry should get you started; it uses the `systemd.automount` features<sup>Note 2</sup> mentioned above:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/mnt/Passport2TB /mnt/rpi-sshfs fuse.sshfs noauto,x-systemd.automount,_netdev,reconnect,identityfile=~/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,default_permissions 0 0
```

The `identityfile` is a ponter to the local (Mint) SSH key file so that the mount can take place without password prompts.

#### Part III: the samba config (if necessary)

This (Part III) is structured differently from Parts I and II. It is based on a simple, contrived example instead of the values in the OP's Question. Part of the reason for this difference is that I wanted to follow the [*official* Samba/CIFS documentation for Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/remote-access.html#samba-smbcifs) as much as possible. And so, Part III is set up as a *stand-alone example*; simple, but hopefully detailed enough to illustrate the key concepts.

1. On the **RPi server**: Make sure that the `samba` server is installed:

```bash
$ which samba
/usr/sbin/samba
$ samba --version
Version 4.13.13-Debian 
#  
#  if either of the above responses from your RPi fail to match these, then proceed w/ following:
#
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install samba samba-common-bin
```

2. On the **RPi server**: Create a folder to share:

```
$ cd  
$ mkdir pishare  
$ chmod 0740 pishare
```

3. On the **RPi server**: Create samba users

```
$ sudo smbpasswd -a pi
```

4. On the **RPi server**: Configure `/etc/samba/smb.conf` on your RPi server; edit file to add the following to the end of the file, and then run `sudo service smbd restart` to load the new config file. Also note, the **share name** is whatever you put inside the brackets; i.e. `[pishare]` - or `[something_else]` if you prefer. Please note that the **share name** (`[pishare]`) has **nothing to do** with the `path` setting:

> [pishare]
> path = /home/pi/pishare
> read only = no
> public = yes
> writable = yes

5. On the **Mint client**: Make sure that `cifs-utils` is installed
6. On the **Mint client**: Create a mount point:

```
$ cd
$ mkdir mysharedpi
```

7. On the **Mint client**: You should now be able to connect from your Mint client to the folder `~/pishare` on the RPi server. Verify this first with a manual (command line) `mount`:

```
$ sudo mount -t cifs -o user=pi,vers=3.1.1 //raspberrypi/pishare /home/pi/mysharedpi  
#
# unmount the share when you've finished with it:
#
$ sudo umount mysharedpi
```

Permissions of any files in `/home/pi/mysharedpi` may be screwed up, but not to worry; we'll fix that:

8. On the **Mint client**: add a permanent mount in `/etc/fstab`

```
$ sudo nano /etc/fstab
#
# add the following line:

//raspberrypi/pishare  /home/pi/mysharedpi  cifs rw,nofail,username=user,password=pass,vers=3,uid=pi,gid=pi,file_mode=0644 0 0
```

9. Verify the mount works. Afterwards, you can change directories (e.g. from `/home/pi/sharedpi` to `/mnt/somethingelse`), and explore other options. Suggestion: Make one change at a time :)
10. In conclusion, we've seen that `samba` is more burdensome to set up and configure than `sshfs`.

---

##### Notes<sup>Note #</sup>

Note 1:

- Note the ***tree*** format, and the ***headings*** produced by `lsblk --fs`. Under the `NAME` column heading, we see the **device name** (`sda`), and immediately underneath it & indented, the **partition name** (`sda1`); i.e. the ***tree*** format. Other useful info for each partition is displayed under the various ***headings***.
- Examining the output for the **partition** `sda1`, note that it is formatted as the `ext4` file system (`FSTYPE`). It has a *user-assigned* `LABEL`. *[`sda1` also has a *machine-assigned* [`UUID`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) which is **not shown** here because of the chosen entry in `/etc/fstab` - as explained below.]* The final ***heading*** shows the `MOUNTPOINT` - **if** it is mounted! In this case (`sda1`) is mounted on the RPi at `/mnt/Passport2TB` (where the `Passport2TB` portion of the mountpoint was specified by an *organized* user  :)

Note 2:
Sadly (or gladly, depending on your point of view), `man fstab` may not be the *final word* on constructing `/etc/fstab`. This due to the introduction of `systemd`, and its underlings `systemd.mount`, `systemd.automount`, `systemd-fstab-generator` into *the mix*. Ref `man systemd.mount`.

Comment: Thanks again for all your help. The answer turned out to be in Section II-A Samba on my Mint machine. The uid and gid options allowed me to set the permissions for the drives properly.

Comment: @TMSpack: That's great, glad it helped.